# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 laravel 5.7

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, phpmyadmin, laravel-5.7

I am getting error in Laravel 5.7:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException
>   SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `stores` (`name`, `matric`, `phone`, `email`, `password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 2019-10-01 16:29:49, 2019-10-01 16:29:49))

This is my form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    @section('title', 'Sign up for customer page')
</head>
<body class="text-center">
@extends('layout.app')

@section('content')

@endsection
@include('include.navbar')
<form class="form-signup" action="{{URL:: to('/store')}}" method="post">
  @csrf

  <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please sign up as customer</h1>
  <label for="inputname" class="sr-only">Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="inputname" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required>
  <label for="inputmatric" class="sr-only">ID matric</label>
  <input type="text" id="inputmatric" class="form-control" placeholder="ID matric" required>
  <label for="inputphon" class="sr-only">Phone No</label>
  <input type="text" id="inputphon" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone No" required>
  <label for="inputemail" class="sr-only">E-mail</label>
  <input type="text" id="inputemail" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" required>
  <label for="inputpassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
  <input type="text" id="inputpassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>


  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"  type="submit">Sign up</button>
  <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">&copy; 2017-2019</p>
</form>

</html>
```

This is `UserController`:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\store;//model name

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $this->validate($request,[
            'name'=> 'request',
            'matric'=> 'request',
            'phone'=> 'request',
            'email'=>'request',
            'password'=> 'request'

        ]);

        //store new customer
        $store = new store;   // valible and model name
        $store-> name = $request->input('name');
        $store-> matric = $request->input('matric');
        $store-> phone = $request->input('phone');
        $store-> email = $request->input('email');
        $store-> password = $request->input('password');

        //save new customer
        $store-> save();

        //redirect
        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

This is the Migration:

```
<?php
//create the customer table
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateStoresTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('stores', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string ('name');
            $table->integer ('matric');
            $table->string ('phone');
            $table->string ('email');
            $table->string ('password');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('stores');
    }
}
```

Comment: Your inputs do not have a `name` attribute, so won't be passed through the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `name` attribute in your html form. Without this attribute your input data won't be passed to the controller and thus you are getting empty values. So add the `name` attribute to the input fields.

```
<label for="inputname" class="sr-only">Name</label>
<input type="text" id="inputname" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required>
<label for="inputmatric" class="sr-only">ID matric</label>
<input type="text" id="inputmatric" name="matric" class="form-control" placeholder="ID matric" required>
<label for="inputphon" class="sr-only">Phone No</label>
<input type="text" id="inputphon" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone No" required>
<label for="inputemail" class="sr-only">E-mail</label>
<input type="text" id="inputemail" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" required>
<label for="inputpassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
<input type="text" id="inputpassword" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
```

And also change your validation

```
$this->validate($request,[
    'name'=> 'required',
    'matric'=> 'required',
    'phone'=> 'required',
    'email'=>'required',
    'password'=> 'required'
]);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also take below steps to bypass this error in your Laravel website :-

1. Update `'strict' => false` in `database.php` file located at path `\config\`
2. Comment below statement in `Kernel.php` file located at path `\app\Http\`

> //
> \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,

Hope it will help someone in future.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to save a null value in the name column even though it is required.

Comment: so how do i solve it i want to store the name into database

Comment: I believe the error is happening while retrieving the value from the field, in the UserController class, try to check if you can retrieve the input values or it is returning null or empty.  --> $store-> name = $request->input('name');

Answer (score 0):

You should name your input with `name="namehere"`
e.g

```
<input type="text" id="inputname" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required>
```

Comment: By that, you can access it in your controller through $request.
$request->name
or if you name your input something like "email" then
$request->email

also can be 

request('name') etc..

Answer (score 0):

You might be sending data in text format:

. [text pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQ1ui.jpg)
. [json pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vuta5.jpg)

Comment: Please explain your solution. This helps OP and others get exactly what is the issue.

Comment: I was having the same problem while using postman to post data in the database, while posting data the language in raw data was selected as TEXT which was supposed to be JSON. That was the mistake which was throwing error.

Answer (score 0):

add attributes to the **model**, it will set default value as blank

```
protected $attributes = [
    'name' => '',
    'matric' => '',
    'phone' => '',
     ...
     .
];
```

and do not validate these fields in **controller**